# How to make that JPanel on JScrollPanel with GridLayout fill only width but not fill height?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I try to make layout as shown below. But I have a poroblem with adding new MyPanels. The first MyPanel fill all its parent (midPanel). How to make that MyPanel take only what is needed height and fill width?

[image]

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

JPanel upPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel midPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel downPanel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("add new Panel");

Main() {
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    this.add(upPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(midPanel);
    this.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(downPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    this.midPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 3));

    upPanel.add(button);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            midPanel.add(new MyPanel());
            midPanel.updateUI();

        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().setVisible(true);
}
}
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    MyPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 5, 5, 5));
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());

        this.add(new JLabel("Nomo:"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe if you use `wrap_content`

Comment: @JosefE.Can you tell me more? it isn't Andorid app. It is Java Swing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you add the mid-Panel in CENTER. Center use the full free space. Set the midPanel to BorderLayout and add another panel to it on North and than add there the MyPanels that works.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

JPanel upPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel newMidPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel downPanel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("add new Panel");

Main() {
    this.setSize(800, 600);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel midPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(upPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(midPanel);
    this.add(jsp);
    this.add(downPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    this.newMidPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 3, 3));
    upPanel.add(button);
    midPanel.add(newMidPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            newMidPanel.add(new MyPanel());
            newMidPanel.updateUI();

        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().setVisible(true);
}
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

MyPanel() {
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 5, 5, 5));
    this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());

    this.add(new JLabel("Nomo:"));
}
}
```

Comment: +1, for general solution. -1, for using the updateUI() method when you add the panel. The updateUI() method is used by internal Swing methods when you do a Look and Feel change and should NOT be used when adding/removing components from a panel. Instead you should be using the `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods.

Comment: @camickr i only adopt the code from TO and add the answer for the question. But you 're right :)